Java Gradle project doesn't build
I recently changed my project from maven to gradle. I followed this guid https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_maven.html and then my first error occurred. So I got something along a deprecated exception. I fixed that but then the next problem happened.  A really long exception. I tried to fix it for 3 hours but now I just feel like giving up.
I hope anyone can help me.
Here is the Gradle scan: https://scans.gradle.com/s/cruao44la4fhq
Here is my build.gradle file
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.15'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.1.0'
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '3.0.1'
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
    implementation("com.google.code.gson:gson:2.10.1")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.17.0")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.17.0")
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:2.17.0")

}

group 'net.jchad'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.10.0'
}


tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'net.jchad.net'
    mainClass = 'net.jchad.net.jchad.installer.mainclass.Main'
}

javafx {
    version = '21'
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    //This caused a deprecated exception while building
    //imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip") 
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}


what if you comment the line mainModule = 'net.jchad.net' out?

net.jchad.net.jchad and similar broken package references seem to be the issue.

Maybe, create a new project following the instructions at openjfx.io or the idea new JavaFX project wizard, then gradually add dependencies and your code from your existing project a bit at time, ensuring it works at each step.  If you have a JPMS modular project (which you seem to do as you declare net.jchad.net), beware of module-related issues, especially as you are using libraries such as fxml, jackson and gson that require reflection (hence open packages in modules) in order to work.

The console logs report no module-info.java file was found.  Ostensibly, that means your project is not modular and thus you should remove the mainModule = 'net.jchad.net' configuration. Though it could be that you forgot to write the module-info descriptor or have it in the wrong location (should be directly under src/main/java if it should exist at all). Additionally, the given module name and your main class's supposed package name are both odd. Why the repetition? That all said, I recommend following jewelsea's advice and providing a [mre] if you still need help.
